# What will you do if your site is hacked?

Tags: consulting

Did you know most hosting companies do not take backups of your website? What will you do if your site is hacked?

Comment: I will redirect all pages to an "under constructions" page, then try to recover and and check the web site

Comment: Welcome to Freelancing! This question has potential to be pretty good, but needs far more expansion and needs some relation to freelancing in there. Please [edit] your question and add something (even an analogy) to expand it a little more!

Comment: There is no universal way of hacking into website, therefore, there is no universal way of how I would behave if my website gets hacked. Please edit your question and make it a bit more specific.

Answer (score 3):

I've actually had this happen before with a personal site.

My host was nice enough to actually give me a chance to get my data off the site, before I wiped it

The very first thing *they* did was cut off access *from* the server out, so it wouldn't affect anyone else. Pretty good idea.

If you're lucky, you might have a host like mine, and actually be able to get your data out. If not... you're out of luck

I did have a backup plan, and I did put it into effect.

Lesson 0: Backups are like shoelaces. Left undone, you will trip and break your face, and its too important to leave to other people. I managed to recover the site from my last known good backups, so all was good.

Lesson 0.0: Build your site with security in mind to start with

Lesson 1: If you can, keep a copy of the site contents for threat analysis.
In my case, someone brute forced my root password

Lesson 2: Learn from lesson 1. When you rebuild your site, make sure you don't make the same mistakes again. My new server has key based auth, I considered building it without a root account.

I'd also add, shared hosting can be a pain, and I tend to run a VPS or a dedicated server these days.